# Formatting a string without code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to reformat a string containing a date without using code behind. The string is in the form YY/MM/DD but needs to be MM/DD/YYYY. I have seen this done given a Date object, however I am limited because it is a string.

So far it seems that I need code behind to do this but at the moment that is unsupported from our vendor.

Comment: "unsupported from our vendor" what?

Comment: When you say "without code behind" do you mean that you need to be able to do it **without using any code at all** or specifically that you don't want code in a code-behind file?

Comment: @CodingGorilla It must be done in XAML, not C#.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, we are building on top of a framework that doesn't allow code behind.

Comment: @H.B. I do what my employer tells me :)

Comment: @AustinHenley So using a converter would not be possible?  I don't think you can do this without using some kind of code; XAML does not give you the ability to parse and manipulate strings, it's really only supports data binding.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Right, that is why I came here. I found `Binding StringFormat` and hoped something like that would be able to help me.

Comment: @AustinHenley: Well if someone wanted to shoot into *my* foot i would try to stop them...

Comment: @H.B. This project was started over a year ago, I just recently started here. They aren't about to redo this project now. Code behind will be supported later but right now I have to fix this.

Comment: @AustinHenley Nope, `StringFormat` is only going to give you the ability to format **other** data types into strings, it's not going to re-arrange an existing string.  As much as I find HB's comments non-constructive, I think he's generally right, you're pretty crippled here.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Thanks, I will try to find an alternative method.

Comment: May I ask what framework does no allow code behind?  XAML is just for layout.  XAML is not meant for business or data processing.

Comment: @Blam And we are using a UDM for the record.

Comment: can "MM/DD/YYYY" be turned into 3 different properties? that's your only bet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question was asked about XAML-only string formatting, here is how you would specifiy the `StringFormat` in your XAML:

Simple:

```
StringFormat=d
```

Longhand: (note the escape curly brackets)

```
StringFormat='\{0:d\}'
```

Custom: (added text)

```
StringFormat='The date is \{0:d\}'
```

A whole `TextBox` using a `StringFormat`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding myProperty, StringFormat='The date is \{0:d\}'}"
```

The syntax is the same as String.Format; however:

- You can only use one parameter
- You have to escape curly braces with a backslash
- If you want to specify more than just the format string, you have to put the whole expression in single quotes

All that being said, what you are trying to do is not simply format a date, but rather you are trying to parse a string as a `DateTime`, then format that `DateTime` as a string.  Of those two steps, only the later can be done in XAML.  It's sad times, but after all, XAML is for markup, not computation.

On the bright side, if you have the ability to reference another assembly in your project, you can implement an `IValueConverter`, which will give you the ability to convert the input string to a `DateTime`, then the StringFormat in XAML would work.  Alternatively, your `IValueConverter` could just export the date in the specified format.

Comment: Do you mean `IValueConverter`?

Comment: Though this doesn't solve my problem, there isn't a good way without code behind and this goes into the details that should be beneficial to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StringFormat property on a Binding to format bound data.  If you have String in XAML, you can bind it as the static source to a TextBlock's Text property, and reformat via the StringFormat.  See this [post](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/) for details.

Comment: How? I am trying to format a string into a string. Can you show me an example of this? That post does not show how to do what I am asking.

Comment: After further investigation, this is incorrect. It does not allow you to format a string but rather it allows you to format a different type into a string given the type's members.